# Use secrets from Azure Key Vault in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I have few azure data factory activities which require username and password to be passed to execute. I am trying to keep this username and password in azure key vault and want to use this in the ADF activity.

I tried an option as shown below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities

But here in the web activity we have to provide the keyvault url, which will be different in different environments. That will be again difficult for ci/cd deployment.

Any other ways we could get azure KV secrets in ADF pipeline task ?

Comment: I know you mentioned that CICD may be difficult, but have you considered building your CICD (build -> env1 -> env2 -> etc) using NPM and ARM? You could then use a keyvault task to obtain the secrets and pass to the ARM deployment segment as override parameters?

Comment: That's looks like a good Idea. (1) Parameterize the fields we want to override. (2) Add a keyvault task in CD pipeline to fetch secrets. (3) Use these secrets to override the required fields.   I will have a look at this!

Comment: Here's a [good article](https://towardsdatascience.com/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-made-simple-building-and-deploying-your-arm-templates-with-azure-devops-30c30595afa5) on the subject Antony. If you need any code snippets, I can show some examples

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to simplify the solution, define the url to Azure Key Vault as a global parameter.
Then, update that global parameter from Release pipeline (Azure DevOps) with appropriate URL per environment.
You can deploy ADF with one of two options, depends on your preferences.
For deployment check these (mine) resources:
[#adftools](https://sqlplayer.net/adftools/)
[Two methods of deployment Azure Data Factory](https://sqlplayer.net/2021/01/two-methods-of-deployment-azure-data-factory/)

Comment: how to update global parameter, refer to doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters#deploying-using-powershell-older-mechanism